What is this meaning of 伺っている?
日向は萌香の願いを分かっているのに、日向はあえて何かを伺っているように思えた。
"hinata understood honaka desires and despite that it looked like hinata..."
What does 伺っている mean here? It seems to mean "to say" in polite form however how can one look "appear to been saying something"?   The character called 萌香 asked Hinata a favor but HInata ignored and 萌香's narration commented this.
伺っている does it have other meanings other than "say"?

伺う here means to observe the situation or atmosphere without explicitly asking or acting. This type of 伺う has nothing to do with keigo. 様子を伺う ("to wait and see") is a common expression. The sentence means 日向 seemed as if he was trying to understand something or extract information from her, before actually acting or making a decision.

Could it be a typo for 窺う?

@JimmyYang According to dictionaries, 窺う indeed seems to be more appropriate, but they share the same etymology anyway. Using 窺う in the sense of "to visit" is clearly wrong, but using 伺う in the sense of "to (silently) observe" is not uncommon. Personally, I haven't made much distinction between 窺う, 覗う, 伺う in this case.
